# Make multiple copies of the same report in PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

When i am trying to upload same report in PowerBI embedded it creates multiple copies. Can someone please let me know how to overwrite existing report when importing.

Comment: There is currently a bug in the import API with regard to the overwrite flag.  As a workaround  you can delete the report and re-import it until the bug is fixed.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli/issues/9

Note: This will not be sufficient in all use cases as it will change the underlying report id.

Comment: @Wallace Breza Thanks for the reply. If id of report is changing then i'll use report name till the issue gets fixed.